# Static library compile problems using Xcode 3.2.3

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

I'm trying to develop a new static library using Xcode 3.2.3.

Xcode is giving strange error messages show below in my G.h file.
What is the cause of these errors?

Charles

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKitDefines.h>

@interface G : NSObject {
  int fontSize, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
}

UIColor *lightslategray;  
  error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

@property int fontSize, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;

-(void) DrawLine:(float)x1 :(float)y1 :(float)x2 :(float)y2 :(float) lineWidth: (UIColor *)color;
  error: expected ')' before 'UIColor'

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably look like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface G : NSObject {
  int fontSize, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
  UIColor *lightslategray;  
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int fontSize;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int canvasWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int canvasHeight;

-(void) drawLine: (float)x1 y1:(float)y1 x2:(float)x2 y2:(float)y2 lineWidth:(float) lineWidth color: (UIColor *)color;

@end
```

It's your first Objective C program ever, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I am new to Objective-c development.
However, your code gives the same error messages.
My original code compiles and runs fine when it is part of an application.  The error occurs only when I try to move this code to a static library project. There must be something else wrong.